# Django template jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have a django template as follows ..

```
...
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="related"}>KIRK</button>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

And a script in the same template

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#related").click( function(event) {
        alert("You clicked the button using JQuery!");
    });
});
</script>
```

On button click I want to show an alert, however, this does not seem to work for me ? I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong ? Is it the way the script is defined or am not using the right selector ?

Comment: You have an extraneous `}` in your `button`.

Comment: Are you including the jquery library??

Comment: Also, you do not need to put the "click" function definition in a document.ready function. Just make sure you are loading the jquery script before the `script` you show above.

Comment: I have loaded this in my base.html <script src="{% static 'sb-admin/js/jquery.js' %}"></script> which is the jquery.js file that I dowloaded off the jquery website.

Comment: Also, make sure you only have one item on the page with the `id="related"`. Go into Firebug and type `$('#related')` on the console and make sure it only returns the button.

Comment: In Firebug, click on the Net tab and make sure your `jquery.js` actually loaded.

Comment: It is loaded since I do get this on my console [28/May/2015 12:17:33] "GET /static/sb-admin/js/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0

Comment: And what does it say when you type `$('#related')` into the console?

Comment: I do not have access to Firebug and it ll be a whole new project to get it downloaded and setup for me since I do not have access to the network at the moment.

Comment: Is this a django specific problem maybe since I am extending the base.html template, which has all the js files ?

Comment: dont need firebug.  press f12....click console......

Comment: No, it's not a Django problem, since I use jquery with Django every day. If you can't install Firebug (and yet you can reach SO?) then use the built-in debugger and do the same things I mentioned above.

Comment: I am using firefox 10.0.10

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="related">KIRK</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

(remove the } )

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever debugger/javascript console you prefer (I use Firebug, but you can do it with the Firefox and Chrome built-in consoles as well, I don't know about IE developer tools, which suck):

- Verify that you load jQuery (and not just some javascript file of your own named jquery.js)
- Verify that jQuery is loaded, and that you have one and only one node in the DOM with the id `related` by typing $('#related')`.
- Verify that your `.click` line is executed *after* jQuery is loaded.
- Try using a version of Firefox that isn't years old. I'm using 38.0, and you're using 10.0? That was released in 2013.

Comment: For some reason I added the script to a separate js file and imported it and it worked.

Comment: Ye I am forced to use that at the moment. No way of updating it. I am stuck with what I got :(

Comment: Thanks for the help though Paul. :)